# How to write this in regular expression

Tags: regex

Product quantity must be an integer number greater than 0 (no decimal point). Any idea how to write this in regular expression perl comptabile

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to allow leading zeroes (i.e., have `01` be invalid), then it's trivial:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Works with nearly all modern regex engines, not just PCRE.

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
[1-9]  # Match one digit between 1 and 9
[0-9]* # Match zero or more digits between 0 and 9
$      # End of string
```